# How to merge pull request conflicts when pull request is from a forked repo?

Tags: git, version-control, tortoisegit, bitbucket-server

I have run into this situation where a coworker forked a repo and made some changes and commited and pushed into git and created a pull request for me. We are using Stash from Atlassian and when I try to merge the pull request I get message to resolve the conflicts first.

Normally if there was conflict during pull or merge into a branch, I would be on the branch into which I have to pull/merge and resolve the conflict and commit and push.

Now that my coworker has forker the repo, I do not have permission to his repo and I am on the main repo. How to go about merge the pull request conflict from his forked repo to the main one ?

thanks

Nohsib

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [Resolve a pull request with conflicts](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/work-with-pull-requests-223220593.html#Workwithpullrequests-Manuallypullrequeststoyourlocalsystem) and [Manually pull requests to your local system](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/work-with-pull-requests-223220593.html#Workwithpullrequests-Manuallypullrequeststoyourlocalsystem).

1. Pull the changes to your local repository
2. Resolve them
3. Merge
4. Push (then, the pull request is marked as accepted)

Answer (score 0):

You can use below steps:

1. Clone main repo into your localbox
2. Go to branch on which pull request has been raised

For above use below

```
git clone <clone_url> -b <branch_name>
```

Run below command

```
git fetch --quiet --no-tags --progress <clone_url> +refs/pull-requests/<PR_NUMBER>/merge:refs/remotes/stash-pull-requests/<PR_NUMBER>
```

Now you can see the conflicts and resolve them.